# Why doesn't my view controller have a back button?

Tags: ios, controller, navigation, storyboard, back

In the picture below (We'll call them storyboard item A, B, C in order from left to right), View controller 'C' does not show a back button but I embedded it in a Navigation Controller. Other Stack overflow posts have not worked. How do I get the back button to show?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move the Navigation Controller to the "first" view controller (ie: the view controller that does the "pushing" or "showing"). The Navigation Controller should not be embedded in the view controller that contains the back button but rather in the view controller upstream of it. This is the main cause of confusion.

[image]